# Prevent EF6 to convert my string to double

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, .net-4.8

I have an SQLite database with a table `Product` which has a field `"Barcode" nvarchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE`.
In this table, I store barcodes like `8699036753633` and `78954106265`.
I have a C# method to get the product by barcode:

```cs
public static Product GetProductByBarcode(string barcode)
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        db.Database.Log = Console.Write;
        //var sql = $"Select * from Product where Barcode=CAST('{barcode}' as NVARCHAR)";
        //var product = db.Product.SqlQuery(sql).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
        var product = db.Product
            .Where(x => x.Barcode == barcode)
            .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

        return product;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the parameter barcode is a string. I even tried casting it into a NVARCHAR but along the way EF6 'thinks' it is a number so tries to convert it to a double. This fails with an `InvalidCastException`:

```
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetDouble(Int32 i)
```

When I add a space or character to the parameter, it is working. No conversion is done. But now the product isn't found.

In my model I also added `[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(255)")]` and in `OnModelCreating` I added `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(t=>t.Barcode).IsUnicode(true).HasColumnType("nvarchar");`

But nothing works. EF6 or the SQLite driver keeps converting my string to a double.
How can I prevent that?

Comment: There is no `nvarchar` or `varchar` data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html Change the column's data type to `TEXT`.

Comment: I added a second column `Barcode2` as Text and even appended `_p` to the value to make it a true text but even though the query runs fine in DB Browser, in my code it keeps returning the `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: I've found the problem. It is really stupid. Besides the barcode I also have a Price column. The data is imported using Excel and some of the Price values had a comma as decimal point instead of a dot. After running `update Product set Price = replace(Price, ',', '.')` my application works again.